# Swing GUI Inconsistently freezing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

EDIT:

> I posted this question over 8 years ago when I was a new programmer. The question itself is not well formed and despite my best efforts, I don't think there is much to salvage from the question itself; however, I do think that there are several answers provided that shine a light on a few important topics. I thought I would attempt to address the wound to my reputation this question has proven itself to be by compiling and expounding upon some of those topics here.

A Friend and I have been trying to write a simple server/client chat application in Java. When we were just using the command line (e.g. java.util.Scanner) everything was fine. It wasn't until we tried building a GUI that we ran into trouble.

Sometimes it would work, sometimes it would freeze and sometimes nothing would happen.

We are somewhat certain that the problem is in the `ask()` method

```
public String ask(String string)
    {
        println(string);        
        hasInput = false;  

        while(true)
        { 
            //System.out.println("working");                
            if(hasInput)
            {
                println("done");
                return processLastInput();//removes the carot ">" from the input and returns it              
            }
        }        
    }
```

but if you uncomment the println statement it
inconsistently works
...here is the rest of the code for you to see

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;


public class ConsoleGUI
{
    private  JFrame FRAME;
    private  JPanel PANEL;
    private  JTextArea CMD_TEXT;
    private  JTextArea CMD_HISTORY;
    private  JScrollPane CMD_HISTORY_SCROLLER;
    private String LAST_INPUT = "";
    private boolean hasInput = false;   

    private final  int screenX = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
    private final  int screenY = (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight(); 

    public ConsoleGUI(String terminalHeader)
    {   
        FRAME = new JFrame(terminalHeader);
        PANEL = new JPanel();
        CMD_TEXT = new JTextArea(">");
        CMD_HISTORY = new JTextArea();
        CMD_HISTORY_SCROLLER = new JScrollPane(CMD_HISTORY_SCROLLER);

        FRAME.setBounds(screenX/2-250,screenY/2-150,500,300);        
        FRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        FRAME.getContentPane().add(PANEL);
        FRAME.setResizable(false);      

        CMD_TEXT.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        CMD_TEXT.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        CMD_TEXT.setFont(new Font("courier new",Font.PLAIN,15));
        CMD_TEXT.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("COMMAND:"));
        CMD_TEXT.setBounds(0,220,490,50);        

        CMD_TEXT.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "NEXT");       
        CMD_TEXT.getActionMap().put("NEXT",new ActivateInputAction());

        CMD_HISTORY.setEditable(false);
        CMD_HISTORY.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        CMD_HISTORY.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        CMD_HISTORY.setFont(new Font("courier new",Font.PLAIN,20));
        CMD_HISTORY.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("CONSOLE:")); 

        CMD_HISTORY_SCROLLER = new JScrollPane(CMD_HISTORY);
        CMD_HISTORY_SCROLLER.setBounds(0,0,490,220);         

        PANEL.setBackground(Color.GRAY);        
        PANEL.setFocusable(true);
        PANEL.setLayout(null);         
        PANEL.add(CMD_HISTORY_SCROLLER);
        PANEL.add(CMD_TEXT);          

        FRAME.setVisible(true);       
    }    

    public void print(Object ob)
    {
        CMD_HISTORY.append(ob.toString());
    }
    public void println(Object ob)
    {
        CMD_HISTORY.append(ob.toString()+"\n");
    }

    public String getLastInput(){return LAST_INPUT;}
    public String processLastInput()
    {
        String newString = LAST_INPUT.replace(">","");
        return newString;
    }
    public boolean hasInput(){return hasInput;}    

    public String ask(String string)
    {
        println(string);        
        hasInput = false;  

        while(true)
        {                 
            if(hasInput)
            {
                println("done");
                return processLastInput();                
            }
        }        
    }

    class ActivateInputAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {            
            LAST_INPUT = CMD_TEXT.getText();
            println(LAST_INPUT);
            CMD_TEXT.setText(">");
            CMD_HISTORY.setCaretPosition(CMD_HISTORY.getText().length());  
            hasInput = true;  
        }
    }    
}
```

if you would like, the server code is below as well

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server 
{
    private static ServerSocket service = null;
    private static String line;
    private static BufferedReader input;
    private static PrintStream output;
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    //private static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static ConsoleGUI Console = new ConsoleGUI("SERVER");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {                   
            int port = Integer.parseInt(Console.ask("PORT:")); 
            Console.println("PORT = "+port);
            service = new ServerSocket(port);
            Console.println(service.getLocalSocketAddress());
            Console.println("WAITING FOR CLIENT TO CONNECT");            
            clientSocket = service.accept();
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            Console.println("CLIENT CONNECTED");
            Console.println(service.getInetAddress());
            while(true)
            {

                line = input.readLine();
                output.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `ask` called?  Swing is a single threaded environment, you never want to do anything that might block the UI thread. You may also want to consider having a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: yah, sorry about the conventions, i know they're lacking and as far as how ask is called i forgot to add the server code earlier, but it is in there now so you can see

Comment: But how is `ask` been called?  I don't see anywhere in your code that it gets called?

Comment: it gets called in the server, in the initial run

Comment: How does the server call a client method on a different machine?  You client code needs to be calling `ask`

Comment: int port = Integer.parseInt(Console.ask("PORT:"));

Comment: the gui is not for the client, in this case it is just for the server so anything that the srever calls for the gui to do is strictly for the server

Comment: See: [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement) for an explanation of why adding a println statement makes the `ask` method work.

Comment: thanks so much :) This is the article I have been looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question over 8 years ago when I was a new programmer. The question itself is not well formed and despite my best efforts, I don't think there is much to salvage from the question itself; however, I do think that there are several answers provided that shine a light on a few important topics. I thought I would attempt to address the wound to my reputation this question has proven itself to be by compiling and expounding upon some of those topics here.

##### Swing is a single-threaded environment.

(Thanks to @MadProgrammer for this answer)

In order to explain concurrency to a new programmer (or my younger self) I would start by first explaining that "threads" are a construct used by the operating system to execute instructions simultaneously.

When a program is run by the OS, or by the JVM in this case, a new thread is spawned and it runs until completion. This means that a *"single-threaded"* paradigm is more or less the default for most programs and it happens to be more intuitive since you can reliably reason about the *in-order execution of your program*. However, a *"multi-threaded"* paradigm often requires changing the way one reasons about writing programs since there *is no longer a guarantee of in-order execution*.

While the statement *"Swing is a single-threaded environment"* is true, it does somewhat skip past something subtle. What isn't obvious to someone learning Swing for the first time is that the program above has not one, but *two* threads. The first one being the actual program thread, and the second one being a thread that is implicitly managed by the Swing framework.

Ultimately what this means is that some parts of Swing are strictly designed to be called by this second thread internally and attempting to perform certain operations from within the main thread can have disastrous consequences since it violates certain expectations that the Swing framework relies on.

The "correct" way to interact with Swing is to:

1. Use Event Listeners.
2. (Mostly) Submit actions to Swing using the Event Queue.
3. Extend Swing components and override specific methods for custom behavior.

##### The Compiler Knows Better?

(Thanks to @Boann and @CDahn for this answer)

Inside of this program is a `while` loop that runs until some condition is met (in this case waiting for `hasInput` to be true). This is often called a *"busy-loop"* or a *"spinner"* and this particular implementation happens to be problematic for several reasons.

Typically when implementing a spinner it is recommended that you call `Thread.sleep()` or platform equivalent inside of the loop. This ensures that your busy-loop is not aggressively and wastefully consuming CPU cycles by notifying the OS Scheduler that this process can be suspended for some time.

This implementation is susceptible to the strange behavior that arises as a result of *"thread-caching"*. This refers to the fact that threads like to keep a local *copy* of variables nearby to reduce read/write times. In most single and multi-threaded environments this is nothing special; however, if two threads ever need to read/write to the same variable it is possible that neither thread will *see* what the other is doing. The recommended way to solve this is by forcing each thread to retrieve the original variable any time a read/write is performed by declaring it `volatile`.

When transforming code into an executable, the compiler often performs a series of aggressive optimizations that are intended to be isomorphic but can sometimes result in strange behavior. One of these optimizations involves a process known as *"hoisting"* where the compiler detects what it thinks to be a constant expression and extracts/substitutes it. Like humans, compilers are very good at reasoning about single-threaded execution, but when a variable is being accessed from multiple threads it can be challenging for a compiler to recognize this interaction. Again, the recommended fix is to declare these shared variables `volatile` so the compiler knows not to perform some of these optimizations.

Comment: I would "suggest" the rather then using `Thread.sleep` (which can often be an indication of a problem), you should employee a "producer/consumer" pattern, then you could make use of monitor blocks instead, which are more efficient then using `Thread.sleep` and periodically check some state

Answer (score 4):

Swing is a single threaded environment, that is, there is an expectation that all interactions with the UI will be done from the Event Dispatching Thread.  Anything that blocks the EDT will prevent the UI from responding to the user or processing new events

You seem to be running foul of this, trying to update the textarea's outside the context of the EDT, which seems to be cause some kind of thread lock (at least under Java 8)

So, I started by updating your `print` methods to update the content from within the context of the EDT

```
public void print(final Object ob) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CMD_HISTORY.append(ob.toString());
        }
    };
    if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        run.run();
    } else {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(run);
    }
}

public void println(Object ob) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CMD_HISTORY.append(ob.toString() + "\n");
        }
    };
    if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        run.run();
    } else {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(run);
    }
}
```

I also updated your `LAST_INPUT` and `hasInput` variables to be `volatile`...

```
private volatile String LAST_INPUT = "";
private volatile boolean hasInput = false;
```

This will ensure that they are updated across thread boundaries properly...

Instead of trying to use a `boolean` flag as a indicator for more information, it would be better to use a object monitor lock, the main reason for this it will put the waiting thread to sleep so it won't consume any CPU...

```
private final Object inputLock = new Object();

//...

public String ask(String string) {
    println(string);
    hasInput = false;

    do {
        synchronized (inputLock) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Wait");
                inputLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    } while (!hasInput);
    println("done");
    return processLastInput();
}
```

I would STRONGLY encourage you to read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) before going much further.  The above examples are hacks at best...

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it was very helpful along with the links you sent... :)

Answer (score 0):

In ask(), hasInput is initialized to false, so you're immediately going into an infinite loop. This will cause the odd behavior as it soaks up any available cycles.

Comment: thats what we thought but... it does sometimes complete the loop because we do get a return. Its odd because its inconsistently working about every eight times run or so it actually returns a value but otherwise it wont return anything, or freezes

Comment: Where else can hasInput be set? As @Mad asked above, how is ask() called? If the main event loop is calling it, you'll freeze, but otherwise you may have a process looping and eating up CPU cycles, making the main event loop starve.

Comment: hasInput gets set in the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method of the class within ConsoleGUI which is the override for the enter key in the jtextarea CMD_TEXT

Comment: I'm going to stick with my previous comment. When main calls ask(), you go into an infinite busy loop until someone clicks in the textarea. Try adding a sleep statement in your ask() while loop and see if all of your troubles go away.